# Get 7 day forecast date for custom location simply iOS

Tags: ios, weather, weather-api

Is it possible to get a 7 day forecast for a location that the user  will enter like "Madrid" from the weather app and then save it for scientific use later? In the best scenario I would like to have an if statement later on like this:

```
#define sunny 1

int monday;

if (monday == sunny) {

//analyze  and return data
}
```

I don't mind using a free API if I can't do it with the apple weather apps.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is link with sample project included 
http://maniacdev.com/2013/06/open-source-ios-wrapper-for-easily-gathering-weather-data-from-free-api

Comment: This is great, simple to use and efficient!